# Why cannot I return T from a contravariant delegate with "in T" and why cannot I take T as parameter for a covariant delegate with "out T"?

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance, contravariance

I am completely new in C# covariant and contravariant concept. I have been following YouTube tutorials and MSDN docs, but they are still confusing. It will be very kind of you if please explain why cannot I return T from a contravariant delegate with "in T" and why cannot I take T as parameter for a covariant delegate with "out T". And, when should I use covariant and when should I contravariant?

Thank you very much of answering.

Edit 1:
I wanted to do something like this:

```
public delegate T ContravariantDelegate<in T>();
public delegate void CovariantDelegate<out T>(T b);
```

Comment: @AliReza: Um, plenty of delegates are. Delegates absolutely support generic variance, too.

Comment: @AliReza `Action<T>`? `Func<T>`?..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-delegates

Comment: yes this is generic delegate. I thought  you want to pass a `delegate`  to T. so  looks like i did not understand your problem. can you provide some code sample and explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Well, the "in" means "Please check that I'm only accepting values *into* the delegate" and "out" means "Please check that I'm only passing values *out* of the delegate" - whereas your examples try to do the exact opposite.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you Sir for your simplification of the terms. I will note them and try to relate it with the examples and tutorials I have been following.